# Importing java native package to react-native project

Tags: android, package, react-native

I'm wondering about adding a java android package in react-native. Is that possible? what is the best practice?

Comment: Do you want to integrate any Android SDK to the React Native project or you want to write some JAVA code and want to use it in React Native Code ?

https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-android 

Do follow this, You will get your things working.